# React Hooks & Async Await: Handling errors with Axios call

Tags: error-handling, axios, react-hooks, try-catch, use-effect

I'm new to `hooks` and `async/await`. I'm trying to handle errors in an Axios call and I'm unsure of how to use `then/catch` or `try/catch` to handle errors with my API call.

In class based React I would handle errors like this:

```js
componentDidMount() {
       axios.get('url')
        .then((res) => {
            // handle response here
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            //handle error here
        })
   };
```

How can I handle Axios error handling when using `useEffect` and `async/await`? I've seen examples using `try/catch` but I can't get it to work in my code.

How can I add error handling to the following API call :

```js
useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            setLoading(true);
            const data =  await axios.get(`https://realtor.p.rapidapi.com/properties/v2/list-for-rent?sort=relevance&city=Miami&state_code=FL&limit=100&offset=0`, headers);

            const properties = data.data.properties;
            console.log(properties);

            /// Iterates through data and grabs all the data for house listings
            const listings =  properties.map((listing, index) => {
                const arr = [];
                arr.push(
                    listing.listing_id,
                    listing.address.line, 
                    listing.address.city, 
                    listing.address.county, 
                    listing.address.neighborhood_name, 
                    listing.address.state,
                    listing.year_built,
                    listing.address.lat,
                    listing.address.lon);

                arr.push(listing.photos.map((photo) => {
                    return photo.href;
                }));

                return arr;
            });

            // House listing data is put into houseData
            //getHouseData(listings);
            setListings(listings);
            setLoading(false);
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the thing about axios. It returns promises, not the value it gets. You need to use that to handle errors. For that you need the `then()` and `catch()` method. Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            setLoading(true);
            await axios.get(`https://realtor.p.rapidapi.com/properties/v2/list-for-rent?sort=relevance&city=Miami&state_code=FL&limit=100&offset=0`, headers).then((response)=>{
             /* DO STUFF WHEN THE CALLS SUCCEEDS */
             setLoading(false);
            }).catch((e)=>{
             /* HANDLE THE ERROR (e) */
            });
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [])
```

Basically, you tell the promise: If the call succeeds, run the function in `then` , with the response as a parameter. If it fails, run the function in `catch`, with the exception as a parameter. Then, you launch fetchData(). You need to handle your data that you received inside the `then` block, because the promise won't directly return it. And if there's an issue, it'll go in the `catch` block, and you handle your error there (maybe set an error message in the state and show it?).

This is a big part of asynchronous programming, and it's still a bit fuzzy for me, but this is a good start to handle your errors more adequatly.